# iOS 10, Swift 3 API call SSL error

Tags: ios, ssl, swift3

I am working on a Mobile app built in cordova which uses REST API. The App works well in itself, but I have a Share Extension built with xcode for which I get this error for an API call.

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9824, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe888624290 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9824, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9824}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.example.com/, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.example.com/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
```

I have this in the Info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>www.example.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.0</string>
                <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Comment: have you replaced 'www.example.com' with your domain ???

Comment: yes, I have that to my domain

Comment: have you tried arbitary load is it working ??

Comment: It didn't help with NSAllowsArbitraryLoads too

Answer (score 1):

Your server SSL is probably not secure or correctly installed.

You should check if it is correctly installed with some of the available webservices out there or something.

[Example](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html)

[or this one](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/)

It can also be that your SSL is **self-signed** and simply not trusted by iOS as trusted.

Answer (score 0):

First, test your server with :

`/usr/bin/nscurl --ats-diagnostics www.mydomain.com`

You said your main app is well-working, so the issue may be in your extension plist.

Did you add the same ATS entry in your extension plist ?

Comment: I have it passing at only **Allowing Arbitrary Loads**,  **TLSv1.0 with PFS disabled**, **TLSv1.0 with PFS disabled and insecure HTTP allowed**.  

I didn't had to put any extra entry for the NSAppTransportSecurity for the main app